# Windows 7 Embedded no spanned volume?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

This is my first experience working with windows 7 embedded and I am trying to create a spanned volume.

I am able to create dynamic discs, but it will not allow me to convert them to anything else. When I delete the partitions and try to create a spanned volume directly with all of the unallocated space, it takes me through the wizard for a spanned volume, but after I am prompted with "are you sure, the drives will be wiped..etc etc", it then tells me there is not enough space to complete the operation.

I looked into possible issues with Win7 embedded and spanned drives, but I could not find anything.

**03/24/14** - (returned from vacation) I noticed this VDS error in Event Viewer[image: DiskManager][image: Event22][image: Space]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your current partition setup in Disk Management?

Comment: Added some shots

Comment: Just guessing here but Windows usually creates a "secret partition" in order to maintain/manage the virtual ones you create (including spanned). Possibly you set the full disk size as target volume size and this is why you are out of space. Try to make a small volume, see how much space "magically disappeared" from full amount and reduce target volume size by that number, after deleting test volume. Let us know if you get the error even for a ways smaller volume size (e.g. half the disk size)

Comment: Tried it and got the same result